# Limit logons per user account in linux.

Tags: linux, login, limits

The current situation is that all users have local configured telnet connections to a red hat server running a simple telnet daemon. I would like to consolidate those locally configured telnet sessions into a emulator that runs in an RDP session. The major hurdle is that doing so allows said users to establish an unlimited amount of telent sessions to the linux host. That isn't acceptable here as there are license issues involved. I'm looking for a way to control the number of sessions a particular user can establish, based on the user. There are some utility type accounts that need to establish many connections. The interactive user sessions though I would like to limit to two per user. 
Is this possible? If so, how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use Debian but it should almost be the same:

In /etc/security/limits.conf (or something like that in Red Hat) perhaps you could use the maxlogins option for those users which may not have unlimited amount of sessions.

Comment: Now this looks interesting. I'll do some reading on the use and format of that config file to see if it can be set up to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Report back you're findings! I'm curious to see.

Answer (score 1):

If by "number of sessions" you mean "number of simultaneous sessions", then yes, you edit /etc/xinetd.conf and in the "telnet services" section, set "instances = 2". Then HUP xinetd or "service xinetd reload."

Comment: Thanks Michael. I wonder, does that allow me enough control to allow for say userA to have a limit of 2 but userB to have a limit of 20? At first glance it doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Donovan. nope, it's just per-service. You'd have to run in.telnetd on different ports, each one configured as a separated "service" in xinetd.conf, with each specifying a different instances number.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help though.